# django_comments adding new field in the model

Tags: django, django-comments

I am trying to add a new field in `django_comment` model. According to the documentation, most custom comment models will subclass the `CommentAbstractModel` model:

```
from django.db import models
from django_comments.models import CommentAbstractModel

class CommentWithTitle(CommentAbstractModel):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

If I generate a migration, then it adds all the fields into migrations (all fields from comment model plus title field).

And after running migrations, `CommentWithTitle` table and `django_comments` table are created. But `django_comments` would be useless (not in use).

Another approach is to generate the table this way:

```
from django_comments.models import Comment

class CommentWithTitle(Comment):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

And it generates the migration with one field only with the reference of `comment_ptr`.

My Question is: which approach is better? I think the first model is good as it has all fields in one table. But that generates the `django_model` which is not in use at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would follow the documentation.

Looking at the implementation, `Comment` is basically just extending `CommentAbstractModel` with `db_table` specified.

```
class Comment(CommentAbstractModel):
    class Meta(CommentAbstractModel.Meta):
        db_table = "django_comments"
```

I'm suspecting that if you do the second option you mentioned, the migration would throw an error because the `db_table` will be created twice.